# How do I get all rows from the second to latest date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have gotten all rows for the latest date like this:

```
SELECT      date, quarter, sales_region, revenue
FROM        regions
WHERE       date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM regions)
ORDER BY    1
```

So how would I get the rows for the second latest date?

I have tried but no luck:

```
SELECT      MAX(date), quarter, sales_region, revenue
FROM        regions
WHERE       date < (SELECT MAX(date) FROM regions)
ORDER BY    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT date, quarter, sales_region, revenue
FROM regions
WHERE date = (SELECT DISTINCT date
              FROM regions r2
              ORDER BY date DESC
              OFFSET 1 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
             )
ORDER BY 1;
```

Another method uses `dense_rank()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*, dense_rank() over (order by date desc) as seqnum
      from regions r
     ) r
where seqnum = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon answered your question precisely, but if you want to get the records for the last two dates in one query, you could use `IN` instead of `=`, and get the top two records with `LIMIT 2`:

```
SELECT date, quarter, sales_region, revenue
FROM regions
WHERE date IN (SELECT DISTINCT date
              FROM regions r2
              ORDER BY date DESC
              LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Starting with version 8.4, you can also use `FETCH FIRST 2 ROW ONLY` instead of `LIMIT 2`.